# RegEx: Capture string without a leading character

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, ecmascript-5

Good evening everybody.

My strings:

```
4x^2+1.5-x
4x^2-x+1.5
1.5+4x^2-x
```

I want to capture the part of those equations without a 'x' behind or another sign than +/- in front of it (1.5). I tried this regular expression:

```
[^\^](\d+(\.\d+)?)(?!x)
```

It matches the searched parts, but with a problem: The match contains the leading +/-. I thought I can solve this with a lookbehind, but since I work with the C++11 library with ECMAScript, this is not supported.

Does somebody know how to solve this?

Thank you :)

Comment: Could you perhaps just look at the first submatch, rather than the match as a whole? That would include only the number.

Comment: can you be more specific about what you actually want? several of those 4's and all of those 2's also do not have an x, + or - behind them.. did you want to match those too? Are you just wanting the first number in the string?

Comment: ah, sorry for late answer :) @CrayonViolent i want to extract the constants from these functions, numbers without a 'x^n' behind them. since they can appear everywhere, at the begin, in the middle or at the end, they can(!) have a '+'/'-' in front of them. if it is a '+', this should not get captured but a '-' should. after these numbers, there can be a '+' or '-', too (rare case, but needs to be noticed).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik the other numbers can also be floats, so they would be captured, too (if this is what you meant, not sure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**rewritten based on even more comments.**

Okay, based on the additional criteria and clarification provided in your comments:

- extract numbers without a 'x^n' behind them.
- they can appear everywhere, at the begin, in the middle or at the end
- they can(!) have a '+'/'-' in front of them. if it is a '+', this should not get captured but a '-' should. (**clarified**:need to capture both, just only SHOW `-`)
- after these numbers, there can be a '+' or '-', too (rare case, but needs to be noticed).
- (**reiterated**: can't use negative lookbehinds)

`(?:[-+]|^)[0-9.]+(?=[-+]|$)`

This will match for the following (there's no good way to format and highlight on here so I wrapped the matches in `[]`):

```
4x^2[+8.15]-x
4x^2-x[+1.25]
[1.9]+4x^2-x
[3]+2x^4-x
x[-6]
[.7]+3x
[-.75]+3x
4x[-0.5]
4x[+0.8]
77x
9.8x
-2.52x^3-4x^2[+1.45]
4x^2[+8.15][-1.5]
```

you will need to strip leading `+`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => +8.15
            [1] => +1.25
            [2] => 1.9
            [3] => 3
            [4] => -6
            [5] => .7
            [6] => -.75
            [7] => -0.5
            [8] => +0.8
            [9] => +1.45
            [10] => +8.15
            [11] => -1.5
        )
)
```

Comment: thank you, but the problem is that i can't use lookbehind (see above) since ECMAScript doesn't support it.

Comment: @TheFunnyTree but also, are you *sure* ECMAScript doesn't support lookbehinds? I coulda swore it supported fixed width lookbehinds, but not variable width? **edit**: well damn. did some googling and you are right.. shady

Comment: @TheFunnyTree you know, perhaps I misunderstood your 3rd point. I interpreted as:"do not capture numbers that are preceded by +. Only capture the ones preceded by -". But now I'm thinking maybe you wanted to capture BOTH, but only want the number to actually show the operator if it's a -.  IOW, capture "-1" AND "+1" but give you "-1" and "1" respectively.  Was my original interpretation right, or is this what you really wanted?

Comment: the first group is good, as stated above, the '-' is needed ;) but about your example with the []-braces: there are three strings where the numbers with '+' dont get captured - why?

**bold** edit: yes, that was the point ;D

Comment: @TheFunnyTree aha, okay.. redid my answer.

Comment: working as intended! \K seems not to be supported, but merging is ok. thank you very much for your effort :)

Comment: ew, seems like there are still problems. tried this:

-2.52x^3-4x^2+1.5

it captures -2.5 at the beginning (just -2.5, not -2.52 o.O) but the +1.5 in the end does not get captured.

Comment: @TheFunnyTree argh.. okay, so I thought about it a while and decided I was over-complicating things. I have updated my answer with a new regex and example vars. Hopefully for realsies this should do it!

Comment: seems to work now, but i noticed another thing:

4x^2+8.15-x+1.5 -> both constants (8.15, 1.5) match,
4x^2+8.15-1.5 -> just 8.15 matches.

i get different results at different ECMAScript-testing tools, including the standard library.. thats awful :F

Comment: @TheFunnyTree okay small modification, 8.15 and 1.5 should both match when in string like that now.  But come on man, do you really think that's a real use case? When would that ever be written like that, vs. `4x^2+6.5` ?

Comment: @TheFunnyTree Also, what do you mean you get different results from different testing tools? if you are getting different results from different tools then it sounds to me like the tool is doing something wrong, or else you need to accommodate based on how you are testing. For example, I have my own regex testing script (realtime ajax-based php using pcre regex). Well I have ability to just put all the example formulas in a list to match against, however, i also have to use the `m` (multi-line) modifier for it to work proper. If i were just testing 1 at a time i wouldn't need to do that

Comment: ..because when you test against a multi-line list, well the char classes will match the newline chars, so you have to use the multi-line modifier. If you ARE doing 1 at a time and getting varied results, then there is something wrong with the tool you are using. This is a fairly simply regex with no trickery; syntax supported by virtually any regex engine out there.

Comment: 1. because there are always users who perform crap in the input ;)
2. i dont know whats up with the testing tool(s) i use. of course i have taken care of `m`, but well..

anyway: works properly now, does what it should, i am happy and even learned something. thank you again :)